# Perl replace string inside file with the filename?

Tags: macos, mac, bash, regex, perl

I need to replace a string in a JSON file with the filename of that file. I successfully matched the string to be replaced using the regex below, but I can't figure out how to get the filename in there to replace the string with.

Note: This is a script used in a rule inside the Hazel app. The app tells me to refer to the file being processed in the script using '$1'. So how do I insert the filename for the file $1 in the find and replace function below?

`perl -pi -e 's/((?<=text": ")\S*(?="))/FILENAME/g' PATH-TO-FILE`

Comment: I didn't understood. You have to substitute the string or is some other application that have to do it? BTW if you have to do it, you can try to use `sed`:  `sed -i 's/TEXT_TO_CHANGE/FILENAME/g' path/to/file/FILENAME` will change all the strings TEXT_TO_CHANGE with FILENAME. Try before without `-i`  to see the effect.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the current file is `$ARGV`

```
perl -pi -e 's/((?<=text": ")\S*(?="))/$ARGV/g' PATH-TO-FILE
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles